# Split View iPad - Reload Table Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, uitableview

I've created a split view project in Xcode and I'm using an `NSXMLParser` to retrieve data from and XML file on the Internet. The data comes in fine and assumes the correct structure, but when I test it out, I found that `UITableViewDelegate` methods are called *before* my NSXMLParser has completed it's run through the data, thus resulting in a blank table. I don't see *any* link in the pre-defined classes to `self.tableView` as cited in so many StackOverflow questions. How would I go about reloading the data in the `RootViewController` after the `NSXMLParser` completes its job?

**EDIT** I've set up some `NSLog` points in my code, and you can see by this console output that the `UITableViewDelegate` methods are being called before the array has any object

```
2011-05-23 19:41:17.591 appname[2804:207] numberOfSectionsInTableView array count: 0
2011-05-23 19:41:17.596 appname[2804:207] numberOfSectionsInTableView array count: 0
2011-05-23 19:41:17.600 appname[2804:207] numberOfSectionsInTableView array count: 0
2011-05-23 19:41:17.610 appname[2804:7303] callParse array count: 2
2011-05-23 19:41:19.911 appname[2804:207] hudWasHidden array count: 2
```

**EDIT2** Let me clarify more: how can I create some sort of connection to the `UITableView` on the left side of the window created with the Split-View template? It's not created in Interface Builder, so I can't do an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'see any link in the pre-defined classes'?

Comment: There is no reference to the `UITableView` displayed on the left in the Split-View template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't have a pointer to the tableView, simply use delegation or notifications to tell your RootViewController to reload the data.

The simply approach would be notifications here I think. Check the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).

In a nutshell, you add look for notification by registering for them like this in the RootViewController :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(xmlDidFinish:)
    name:@"finishXML" object:nil];
```

And in your XMLParser, you actually post the notification when you're done like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"finishXML" object:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a method `reloadData` which will call the tableViews delegate methods again (thus repopulating the table). Once the parser completes it's job, call `[tableView reloadData]` where tableView should be replaced with your UITableView instance.

Comment: I know that, but I don't have any pointers to the table I need to reload the data into, that was basically my question.